# I don't want to log a jpa query from axboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, jpa

I don't want to log a jpa query from axboot.

This framework does not contain any configurable xml files, only properties files.

If you modify the values in properties, the query is still being stacked in the log.

How do I modify it?

```
2019-07-01 15:14:23 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  com.chequer.axboot.core.db.aop.StatementMethodInterceptor:invoke:149 
[query] - 2019-07-01 15:14:23 - 
   select
        user0_.USER_CD as USER_CD1_4_0_,
        user0_.CREATED_AT as CREATED_2_4_0_,
        user0_.CREATED_BY as CREATED_3_4_0_,
        user0_.UPDATED_AT as UPDATED_4_4_0_,
        user0_.UPDATED_BY as UPDATED_5_4_0_,
        user0_.agent_id as agent_id6_4_0_,
        user0_.DEL_YN as DEL_YN7_4_0_,
        user0_.EMAIL as EMAIL8_4_0_,
        user0_.HP_NO as HP_NO9_4_0_,
        user0_.IP as IP10_4_0_,
        user0_.LAST_LOGIN_DATE as LAST_LO11_4_0_,
        user0_.LOCALE as LOCALE12_4_0_,
        user0_.MENU_GRP_CD as MENU_GR13_4_0_,
        user0_.PASSWORD_UPDATE_DATE as PASSWOR14_4_0_,
        user0_.REMARK as REMARK15_4_0_,
        user0_.USE_YN as USE_YN16_4_0_,
        user0_.USER_NM as USER_NM17_4_0_,
        user0_.user_no as user_no18_4_0_,
        user0_.USER_PS as USER_PS19_4_0_,
        user0_.USER_ROLE as USER_RO20_4_0_,
        user0_.USER_STATUS as USER_ST21_4_0_ 
    from
        _user user0_ 
.....
```

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
hibernate.order_inserts=true
hibernate.order_updates=true
hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false

axboot.log.level=ERROR
axboot.log.slack.enabled=false
axboot.log.slack.webHookUrl=
axboot.log.slack.channel=error_logs
axboot.log.database.enabled=false
axboot.log.adminUrl=
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark... -> try `hibernate.show_sql=false` instead of `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false`. As I can see both the *show sql* and *format_sql* are set to true.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work out. And I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the logging level of to ERROR

```
 logging.level.com.chequer.axboot.core.db.aop.StatementMethodInterceptor=ERROR
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work out. And I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the properties file was meaningless.

And finally I found the answer.

I added an error level to error LoggerContext on axBootLogbackAppender.

Add 'loggerContext.getLogger("ROOT").setLevel(Level.ERROR);' to 'axBootLogbackAppender' method of 'CoreApplicationContext' file.

I will find the answer. as always hahaha